# Division in C language

Tags: c, floating-point, integer-arithmetic, binary-operators

Hello fellas hope you all doing well i am kinda newbie in C language, I just need to ask a basic question that is that when i divide numbers in C like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
   float a = 15/4;
   printf("%.2f", a);
}
```

the division happens but the answer comes in a form like 3.00(which is not correct it did'nt count the remainders)
But when i program it like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
   float a = 15;
   float b = 4;
   float res = a/b;
   printf("%.2f", res);
}
```

this method gives me the correct answer. So i want to ask the reason behind the difference b/w these two programs why doesn't the first method works and why the second method working?

Comment: `15/4` is integer (i.e. truncating) division, because both of the operands are of type `int`.  In C, the type of division you get depends on the types of the operands. In some programming languages, truncating division and fractional division proper have different operator names; in C, they share the same token which is resolved by the compiler via a kind of operator overloading (though C doesn't have user-definable operator overloading, it has *de facto* built-in overloading).

Comment: Both answers are correct. The "/" symbol between two integers denotes integer division.

Comment: Ugh, I voted it as a duplicate without seeing that the duplicate I voted for was for python!

Comment: Thanks guys i got my answer!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this expression

```
15/4
```

the both operands have integer types (more precisely the type `int`). So the integer arithmetic is performed.

If at least one operand had a floating point type (float or double) as for example

```
15/4.0
```

or

```
15/4.0f
```

then the result will be a floating point number (in the first expression of the type `double` and in the second expression of the type `float`)

And in this expression

```
a/b
```

the both operands have floating point types (the type `float`). So the result is also a floating point number.

Comment: I see I see now i understand. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

When you state your varable to float you automatically casting the values he get from the equation.
For example:
Float a = 2/4 it's like writing float a = float(equation).
Take care,
Ori